# Android NoSuchElemenException in Async Task with LinkedList

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-asynctask, semaphore

i got a really weird problem, it makes no sense at all. Im using an Async Task in Android to print some data on my UI. The doInBackground-Part looks like this:

```
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            Double lastVal = 0.0;
            while (!stopTask){
                try{
                    popDataSemaphore.acquire();
                    if (data.size() > 0){
                        Double data = me.data.pop();

                        if (!data.equals(lastVal))  {
                            publishProgress(data); 
                            lastVal = data;
                        }

                    }
                    popDataSemaphore.release();
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            return null;
        }
```

In this task you can see the "me.data.pop()". Data is a modified LinkedList. The only modification is, that at a given size, it wont add any more values. It just ignores them. The LinkedList ist filled by another Async Task.

As you can see, im using a Semaphore. This is cuz before android 3.0, Async Tasks were executed on more than one thread. 
Strange thing is, from time to time a "NoSuchElementException" is thrown at the Line "Double data = me.data.pop()". How is that possible?

In my modified LinkedList i only override the add-Method:

```
@Override
public boolean add(E o) {
    if(limit == size())
        return false;
    super.add(o);
    return true;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Well, i didnt really solve the problem - i still dunno why this is happening - but i found another way. I just used an ArrayList and made the same modification as for the LinkedList. With the ArrayList, no exception occures. Must be something about the LinkedList. Well, thx for the help.

Comment: if your pop is removing an element as the name suggests, probably your linked list is has no more elements to provide you with...did you check this possibility...just giving in my two grains

Comment: What is the variable `me`? Are you sure you're referring to the same list in `data.size()` as you are in `me.data.pop()`?

Comment: might help http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html

Comment: me = this in the class that holds the Async Task. I call the Async Task in a Method "printdata()" in this class. Yes, its refering to the correct List, because i checked it with sysout. Its printing the correct data. I also get the data print out on my display.

Comment: @Why-K-Rum: Thx, i checked that out already. Still makes no sense, that it is thrown. The semaphore is "private Semaphore popDataSemaphore = new Semaphore(1, true);" by the way. I switched from false to true, just to check if it has something to do with it. There should never be a state, in which "me.data.pop()" is called if the list is empty. Its prevented by the semaphore and the if (data.size())...